# Counting columns excluding 0 value

Tags: sql, datetime, count, amazon-redshift, distinct

I have the following data (actually spans over years but for this example, I only included 4 months)

```
id  created_at  staff
--------------------------------
1   2010-01-01  Coder
2   2010-01-15  Developer
3   2010-03-01  Data Analyst
4   2010-01-20  Developer
5   2010-03-13  Data Analyst
6   2010-04-05  Tester
7   2010-04-01  Tester
8   2010-04-04  Business Analyst
9   2010-01-22  Business Analyst
10  2010-01-25  Coder
```

I then use the following query to count the staff by months.

```
select staff,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_01,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-02-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_02,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-03-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_03,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-04-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_04
from mytable
group by staff
```

Below is an example of the output that the above SQL produces.

```
staff               2010-01   2010-02   2010-03   2010-04   
----------------------------------------------------------
Coder               2         0         0         0
Developer           2         0         0         0
Data Analyst        0         0         2         0
Tester              0         0         0         2
Business Analyst    1         0         0         1
```

I am now trying to count the number of columns that have a value. The expected outcome I am looking for is

```
staff               months   2010-01   2010-02   2010-03   2010-04  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Coder               1        2         0         0         0
Developer           1        2         0         0         0
Data Analyst        1        0         0         2         0
Tester              1        0         0         0         2
Business Analyst    2        1         0         0         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use count(distinct) as well:

```
select staff,
    count(distinct date_trunc('month', created_at)) as months
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_01,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-02-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_02,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-03-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_03,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-04-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_04
from mytable
group by staff
```

Comment: Thanks @PRIN, now I am feeling rather foolish as to how easy that was... BTW, you're missing a closing parenthesis after `created_at`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `count(distinct)`:

```
select staff,
       count(distinct date_trunc('month', created_at)) as num_months,
       sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_01,
       sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-02-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_02,
       sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-03-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_03,
       sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-04-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_04
from mytable
group by staff
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just count the distinct months with `count(distinct)`:

```
select staff,
    count(distinct date_trunc('month', created_at)) as cnt_month,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-01-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_01,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-02-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_02,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-03-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_03,
    sum(case when date_trunc('month', created_at) = date '2010-04-01' then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2010_04
from mytable
group by staff
```